# Mirroring git's master branch into SVN

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

Our team is a big fan of git but unfortunately (for us) our company only uses SVN. I am aware of `git svn`'s existence, but it doesn't work well with many tools.

To avoid bringing over all our branches to SVN (we use gitflow, so a lot of branches), what I'm looking for is a solution that would mirror my git's repository's master branch (hosted on GitHub or similar) to SVN's trunk.

I am not concerned with my SVN being unaware of the branches we are currently working on.

Ideally, merging to the `master` branch from `develop` would result in the code and its history making it to SVN's trunk.

Any idea how to achieve this or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention GitHub, git repositories on GitHub can be accessed [from a Subversion client](https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/). More generally, I've found [SubGit](http://www.subgit.com/remote-book.html) to be much better than git-svn for mirroring Git and Subversion.